# how it is a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The augmentation ideal of a group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$, as a free abelian group, has basis {$x-1: x \in G$ and $x \neq 1_G$}

So if $G = \mathbb{Z}$, then the augmentation ideal would have $\mathbb{Z}-0$ as a basis according to the definiton. However, this basis is obviously not linearly independent. Then how it is basis? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You really need to make a distinction between the group $\Bbb Z$ and the ring $\Bbb Z$ here. Instead of taking the group ring of $\Bbb Z$, take a multiplicative group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, say $G=\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$. This is the free group of rank one. Then
the augmentation ideal of $\Bbb Z G$ has $\Bbb Z$-basis $\{g^n-1:n\ne0\}$.